# My facebook app make Infinite loop in sdk 3.1.1

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, infinite-loop

I have iframe facebook app but reload making infinite loop.

Yesterday work fine, but not to day.

I'm using javascript and php sdk 3.1.1 with this code:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
  FB.init({
    oauth: true, // turn oauth 
    appId  : 'myappId',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
 FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
 </script>

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        var query = FB.Data.query('select publish_stream from permissions where uid={0}', response.authResponse.userID);
........................
      }
 }
```

If I delete `"<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>"` line, it does not infinite loop, but the app not work like i want.

Comment: When you remove the Facebook connect reference in what is it not working? You indicate you're in an infinite loop where? It's clears that you are having issues, but you are not being specific enough in your question to receive help.

Comment: the FB login is not working on your website. Were you able to successfully code it or this is something wrong from FB API so we can not do anything no matter what all we try in asp.net? Please let me know. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook migrated JavaScript SDK to support OAuth2, and requiere that all apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 by October 1, 2011 (but last time was december 14 2011) therefore, I change:

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
........................
      }
```

by

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
........................
      }
```

because the app was initialized with OAuth 2.0 enabled.

case closed.